# How to receive $_SESSION variable as a parameter in onload event

Tags: javascript, php, session

I'm trying to receive a SESSION variable as a parameter in a javascript function called in an `onload` event, but nothing happens.

My aim is to change the background color of the last input pressed. This inputs are on a sidebar, the last one pressed has to change to a different color and the rest have to go white.

If there's another way to do this please I would really like to know it. Thanks.

Here is my code.

```
<body onload="identificar_hijo('divGeneral',<?php echo $_SESSION['name_sidebar'];?>)">
<?php //getting the $url of this page?>
<script type="text/javascript">    
    function identificar_hijo(divID,selectedID)
    {
        //using function getChildren() to identify the divs children and change background Colors.
    }
</script>        
    <form name="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $url;?>" method="post">
        <div id="divGeneral" style="margin-left: 5%; margin-right: 5%;">
            <?php
            //saving the session variable
            $_SESSION['name_sidebar'] = $name_sidebar;              
            ?>
                <div id="<?php echo $name_sidebar;?>">
                    <input type="submit" name="<?php echo $name_sidebar;?>" id="<?php echo $name_sidebar;?>">
                </div><?php                
            }?>    
        </div></form></body>
```

Comment: What is the generated source?  Looks like you need quotes around the 2nd argument, unless it's a javascript variable name you're storing in the session.  You will notice this if you "view source".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put php code into `''`:

```
<body onload="identificar_hijo('divGeneral','<?php echo $_SESSION['name_sidebar'];?>')">
```