# pass session variable as parameter in onload() function call

Tags: javascript, php, session

what am I doing wrong here, I am trying to send the session variable $_SESSION["post-code"] as a parameter as follows...

```
<body onload="getLocation('<?php echo $_SESSION['post-code'];?>')">
```

in my js file I have the following function

```
function getLocation(postCode) { }
```

everything was working fine before I tried to test passing in a parameter. I get console errors as follows...

for the html...  Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

for the js...  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token -

is what I am trying to do possible, I found this on here...

[How to receive $_SESSION variable as a parameter in onload event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27197857/how-to-receive-session-variable-as-a-parameter-in-onload-event)

...which I assume worked given the 'right answer' marker, so what am I doing differently, sorry if this is obvious?

thanks for any help.

Comment: I think you forgot quote: ```<body onload="getLocation('<?php echo $_SESSION['post-code'];?>')">```

Comment: Can you post the value of `$_SESSION['post-code']` ?

Comment: Take a look at the resulting html code you create. Maybe post that here.

Comment: thanks VirginieLGB the quotes fixed the problem, after I fixed separate issue in my js file - can't give you credit as you didn't offer 'Answer', or can I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include quotes. Like this

```
<body onload="getLocation('<?php echo $_SESSION['post-code'];?>')">
```

As onLoad is a normal html attribute, that gets processed as javascript

Comment: hi, thanks, I added quotes and same result, have amended my code

Comment: and please post all your relevant code (the functions, etc)

Comment: ok, the quotes did work :-) I had a separate error in my js file which I now corrected....thanks guys

Answer (score -2):

Here is it

```
   <body onload="function(){getLocation('<?php echo $_SESSION['post-code'];?>')}">
```

Comment: thanks, I now get this...Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token -
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

Comment: per above this did work, thanks...after I corrected a separate error in my js file